# Trouble understanding the proof that if $X^n$ is a direct sum of $X^p$ and $X^q$, then $n = p + q$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm following the proof from a textbook (finite-dimensional vector spaces), but I  don't understand the reasoning behind two inequalities ($n>p+q$ and $n<p+q$). They seemingly pop out of nowhere. It's probably really obvious, but i just don't know. It goes something like this:

Assume that $X^n = X^p \bigoplus X^q$.

If $e_1,...,e_p$ is basis in $X^p$, and  $e_1',...,e_q'$ is basis in $X^q$, let's prove that vectors $e_1,...,e_p,e_1',...,e_q'$ are linearly independent.

From $\sum_{k=1}^p \alpha_k e_k + \sum_{k=1}^q \alpha_k' e_k' = 0$ we get that $a+b=0$, where $a$ is the first sum, and $b$ is the second one. Since $a \in X^p$, and $b \in X^q$, and the sum is direct, we know that $a=0$, and $b=0$.

But for $a=0$ we have $\sum \alpha_k e_k = 0$, so $\alpha_1=...=\alpha_p=0$. The same goes for $b$, so $\alpha_1' = ... = \alpha_q' = 0$.

Which means that $e_1,...,e_p,e_1',...,e_q'$ are linearly independent. But that means that $n > p + q$.

**The other side:**

Every $x \in X^n$ can be written as $x = y+y'$ for $y\in X^p, y' \in X^q$. So for
$$ y = \sum_{k=1}^p \alpha_k e_k \quad\quad\quad y' = \sum_{k=1}^q \alpha_k' e_k', $$

we get $x = \sum_{k=1}^p \alpha_k e_k + \sum_{k=1}^q \alpha_k' e_k'$, which means that $n < p + q$.

There for $n = p + q$.

**Edit**

Like commentors pointed out it shouldn't be a sharp inequality,
but the book is kind of [poorly printed so](https://imgur.com/a/Yj3PJqO).

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? What do you not understand?

Comment: Presumably you mean $n≤p+q$ and conversely.

Comment: @BenSteffan Specificity with how they came up with those two inequalities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: The inequalities are not sharp, i.e. you only get $n\geq p+q$ and $n\leq p+q$ which then together yield $n = p+q$.

Now, for your actual question, think about how the dimension of a vector space $X$ is defined in the first place: The dimension of $X$ is the *largest possible* $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ so that there exist $n$ *linearly independent* vectors in $X$ (of course, one has to first invest some  efforts into showing that this quantity is well-defined).

In your first step, you show that there exist vectors $e_1,...,e_p,e_1',...,e_q'$ in $X$ which are linearly independent, so the dimension of $X^n$ (again, the largest possible number of linearly independent vectors) is at least $p+q$. This gives $n\geq p+q$.

In the second step, it is shown that any vector in $X^n$ can be written as a sum of vectors from $X^p$ and $X^q$, or in other words there can only be at most $p+q$ linearly independent vectors. This gives $n\leq p+q$.

Comment: Now i see, thank you! And you are right, those are not sharp inequalities. The book is poorly printed, so it looks like a sharp one, but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you must have proven the following theorem in your course/textbook, or something equivalent, when discussing bases, as the results you describe for direct sums rely upon it.

**Theorem:** Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space, with $\dim(V)=n$, and $S =\{v_1, \dots, v_m\}$ be some finite collection of vectors on $V$.

1. If $S$ is linearly independent, then $m \le n$
2. If $S$ spans $V$, then $m \ge n$.

In both cases, we have equality if and only if $S$ is a basis for $V$.